# Cutting out row and column of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D-array (NumPy array) and want to get out a sub-array that is the result of cutting out a given row and column.

As an example I have found one way:

```
In [111]: mat
Out[111]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]])

In [112]: np.delete(np.delete(mat, 3, 1), 0,0)
Out[112]: 
array([[ 6,  7,  8, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 20],
       [21, 22, 23, 25]])
```

This took out row 0 and column 3. However, I don't think this is very pretty, and as far as I can tell it has to allocate space for two extra arrays, one for each return from `np.delete`.

So the question is, is there some way to get the desired result in a more read- and memory efficient way? Ideally something that only gives me a reference to the correct elements of the array, and not a full copy. Note that the example is not the array I need this for, answer should work for a `n x n` where row `i` and column `j` is deleted.

Comment: You might consider [masked arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#rationale) which will allow you to, in some sense, "cut out" rows and columns of your array without copying data. The overhead is a memory-efficient bitmask. Otherwise, it will be hard to do this, I believe, without creating a copy.

Comment: If you can't express the selection (what you keep) with slice notation (start,stop,step) you can't avoid making one or more copies.

Comment: It seems to me that this is in fact the case. I can't seem to get the right behavior from masked matrices either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.column_stack` with a simple indexing :

```
>>> np.column_stack((A[1:,:3],A[1:,4:]))
array([[ 6,  7,  8, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 20],
       [21, 22, 23, 25]])
```

Comment: This seems to be the fastest (and most readable) of the suggested answers. The result is still a new array, but that seems inevitable.

Answer (score 1):

**Actually delete**

To actually delete elements, here's one using [`broadcasted boolean indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) with [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) -

```
row_cut = 0
col_cut = 3

m,n = mat.shape
row_mask = ~np.in1d(np.arange(m),row_cut)
col_mask = ~np.in1d(np.arange(n),col_cut)
out = mat[(row_mask[:,None]*col_mask)].reshape(-1,n-1)
```

Runtime tests -

```
In [220]: def cut_valid_array(mat,row_cut,col_cut):
     ...:   m,n = mat.shape
     ...:   row_mask = ~np.in1d(np.arange(m),row_cut)
     ...:   col_mask = ~np.in1d(np.arange(n),col_cut)
     ...:   return mat[(row_mask[:,None]*col_mask)].reshape(-1,n-1)
     ...: 

In [221]: mat = np.random.randint(0,100,(1000,1000))

In [222]: %timeit np.delete(np.delete(mat, col_cut, 1), row_cut,0)
10 loops, best of 3: 26.3 ms per loop

In [223]: mat = np.random.randint(0,100,(1000,1000))

In [224]: %timeit cut_valid_array(mat,row_cut,col_cut)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.48 ms per loop
```

**Keep a valid mask**

You could also create a 2D mask of valid elements and of course of the same shape as the input array for a more memory and time efficient approach, like so -

```
m,n = mat.shape
row_mask = ~np.in1d(np.arange(m),row_cut)
col_mask = ~np.in1d(np.arange(n),col_cut)
mask2D = (row_mask[:,None]*col_mask)
```

Runtime tests -

```
In [225]: def cut_valid_mask(mat,row_cut,col_cut):
     ...:   m,n = mat.shape
     ...:   row_mask = ~np.in1d(np.arange(m),row_cut)
     ...:   col_mask = ~np.in1d(np.arange(n),col_cut)
     ...:   return (row_mask[:,None]*col_mask)
     ...: 

In [226]: mat = np.random.randint(0,100,(1000,1000))

In [227]: %timeit np.delete(np.delete(mat, col_cut, 1), row_cut,0)
10 loops, best of 3: 27 ms per loop

In [228]: mat = np.random.randint(0,100,(1000,1000))

In [229]: %timeit cut_valid_mask(mat,row_cut,col_cut)
1000 loops, best of 3: 414 µs per loop
```

Comment: I like this very much, but I can't seem to get the right behavior from masked arrays. The first suggestion I do like, but the accepted answer is a bit faster (and a bit shorter). Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Bendik When you use the mask on the input array, you would get a 1D array. So, after that you need to reshape : `.reshape(-1,n-1)` as stated in the function `def cut_valid_array`. Glad to help!

Comment: Yes, I gathered that from the first function. Just seems that I can't get what I need from masked arrays... Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your solution is that bad, the problem is that by removing arbitrary "rows" and "columns" you're disrupting the structure of the array (check out [strides](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#internal-memory-layout-of-an-ndarray)), and the only way to obtain an array with that new structure is to reallocate it.

In general only [certain slicing operations](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#arrays-indexing) return a memory-efficient view of the array, for example with regular slicing (no fancy things, such as lists).

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
mat[[1,2,3,4],:][:,[0,1,2,4]]
```

should give the same result?

Comment: and if the array is `n x n` and i want to cut out row `i` and column `j`? I should have said that the example is not the array in the example is not the one I'm working with.